# Is there a way to save the applied Keras dropout tensors for future use?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dropout

In my Keras CNN, I'm applying dropout during inference for some uncertainty measures. For a new idea I have, I need to be able to know which units in the network were turned off. So, I want to be able to save, or get as callback, the applied dropout tensors of zero's and one's. I was wondering if someone here might know a way to do this.

Many thanks, Ward